# Posting XML using python requests

Tags: python, xml, post, teamcity, python-requests

I have the following code that posts xml to teamcity to create a new VCS root:

```
def addVcsRoot(vcsRootId, vcsRootName, projectId, projectName, buildName, repoId, teamAdminUser, teamAdminPass):
     headers = {'Content-type': 'application/xml'}
     data = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
        "<vcs-root id=\"" + vcsRootId + "\" " + "name=\"" + vcsRootName + "\" " +
        "vcsName=\"jetbrains.git\" href=\"/app/rest/vcs-roots/id:" + vcsRootId + "\">" +
        "<project id=\"" + projectId + "\" " "name=\"" + projectName + "\" " "parentProjectId=\"_Root\" " +
        "description=\"Single repository for all components\" href=\"/app/rest/projects/id:" + projectId +  
        "\" " + "webUrl=\"http://teamcity.company.com/project.html?projectId=" + projectId + "\"/>" +
        "<properties count=\"11\">" + "<property name=\"agentCleanFilesPolicy\" value=\"ALL_UNTRACKED\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"agentCleanPolicy\" value=\"ON_BRANCH_CHANGE\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"authMethod\" value=\"PASSWORD\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"branch\" value=\"refs/heads/master\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"ignoreKnownHosts\" value=\"true\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"submoduleCheckout\" value=\"CHECKOUT\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"url\" value=\"https://source.company.com/scm/" +repoId +  "/" + buildName + 
        ".git\"" + "/>" + "<property name=\"username\" value=\"" + teamAdminUser + "\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"usernameStyle\" value=\"USERID\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"secure:password\" value=\"" + teamAdminPass + "\"/>" +
        "<property name=\"useAlternates\" value=\"true\"/>" + "</properties>" +
        "<vcsRootInstances href=\"/app/rest/vcs-root-instances?locator=vcsRoot:(id:" + vcsRootId + ")" +
        "\"" + "/>" + "</vcs-root>")
     url = path + 'vcs-roots'
     return requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data)
```

I did a get to see what the xml file should look like and have made it so I can input different parameters for different builds, and the script works fine.  My question is: is there a more elegant way to do this?  Posting this long string with concatenation seems ugly and inefficient.  What are some other ways to post xml using requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to rewrite it all but using str.format, kwargsa and triple quoted a string will make the code a lot less cluttered:

```
def addVcsRoot(**kwargs):
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/xml'}

    data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <vcs-root id="{vcsRootId}"  name="{vcsRootName}"
        "vcsName="jetbrains.git" href="/app/rest/vcs-roots/id:"{vcsRootId}"\>""".format(**kwargs)
```

Then:

```
addVcsRoot(vcsRootId=1234, ......)
```

or if you want to keep the named args as is:

```
def addVcsRoot(vcsRootId, vcsRootName, projectId, projectName, buildName, repoId, teamAdminUser, teamAdminPass)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/xml'}

    data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <vcs-root id="{vcsRootId}"  name="{vcsRootName}"
    "vcsName="jetbrains.git" href="/app/rest/vcs-roots/id:"{vcsRootId}"\>"""\
    .format(vcsRootI=vcsRootId, vcsRootName=vcsRootName.....)
```

Comment: Thank you! This cleaned it up a lot.